# dplyr slice: prioritise based on a vector when there is a tie

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to achieve the following task with `dplyr`.

I have a `data.frame` as follows

```
head(test_dat)

      PEAK MOTIF
    1   p1    m1
    2   p1    m2
    3   p1    m3
    4   p2    m1
    5   p2    m1
    6   p2    m2
    7   p3    m5
    8   p3    m3
    9   p3    m3
```

I would like to assign a unique `MOTIF` to `PEAK` depending how many time it is found with that particular `PEAK` value.

```
test_dat %>% 
+   dplyr::group_by(PEAK) %>% 
+   dplyr::count(MOTIF) %>% 
+   dplyr::slice(which.max(n))
```

This gives me

```
  PEAK  MOTIF     n
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 p1    m1        1
2 p2    m1        2
3 p3    m3        2
```

Which is perfectly fine except when there is a tie for a `PEAK` in column `n`, it chose the first one. That is in the example, for `p1`, m1, m2, m3 are found once, but in the result `m1` is assigned. Instead, I would like to assign `MOTIF` value to `PEAK` according to a vector, e.g.

```
motif_order = c("m2", "m1", "m3", "m5")
```

so that makes the result

```
  PEAK  MOTIF     n
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 p1    m2        1
2 p2    m1        2
3 p3    m3        2
```

I was searching `rank` and `slice` functions, but I didn't find a way to achieve this within `dplyr`. Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(MOTIF = factor(MOTIF, levels = c("m2", "m1", "m3", "m5"))) %>%
  add_count(PEAK, MOTIF) %>%
  group_by(PEAK) %>%
  arrange(n, MOTIF) %>%
  slice(which.max(n))
```

Output:

```
  PEAK  MOTIF     n
  <chr> <fct> <int>
1 p1    m2        1
2 p2    m1        2
3 p3    m3        2
```

Instead of `factor(MOTIF, levels = c("m2", "m1", "m3", "m5"))` you can also reference `motif_order` if you have it already defined in the environment, e.g. `factor(MOTIF, levels = motif_order)`.

If you're interested, something like that would also work in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, MOTIF := factor(MOTIF, levels = motif_order)][, .N, by = .(PEAK, MOTIF)][
  order(N, MOTIF), .SD[which.max(N)], by = PEAK]
```

Output:

```
   PEAK MOTIF N
1:   p1    m2 1
2:   p2    m1 2
3:   p3    m3 2
```

Comment: That's a good trick to factorize the column. Thanks a lot. Working perfect.